# Visualization into a select box

Tags: javascript, visualization

I 'm new in javascript and i 'm trying to put the code of a visualization into a select box at selection02. 
My visualization code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/static/modules/gviz/1.0/chart.js"> {"dataSourceUrl":"//docs.google.com/spreadsheet/tq?key=0AihqKzH-MgAndERnaFVsYk1RLUM3S0pDSmNjcEQ4M1E&transpose=0&headers=0&range=A2%3AB13&gid=0&pub=1","options":{"vAxes":[{"useFormatFromData":true,"viewWindowMode":"pretty","viewWindow":{}},{"useFormatFromData":true,"viewWindowMode":"pretty","viewWindow":{}}],"booleanRole":"certainty","animation":{"duration":0},"useFirstColumnAsDomain":true,"hAxis":{"useFormatFromData":true,"viewWindowMode":"pretty","viewWindow":{}},"isStacked":false,"width":454,"height":285},"state":{},"chartType":"AreaChart","chartName":"\u0393\u03c1\u03ac\u03c6\u03b7\u03bc\u03b1 1"} </script>
```

These are my two linked select boxes. I was trying to get this code from another file but something went wrong. Also can i make selectbox2 being disappeared until i make my first choice?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

function allagi()
{
   if (document.getElementById("selection01").selected==true)
   {

   }
   else if (document.getElementById("selection02").selected==true)
   {

   }
   else if (document.getElementById("selection03").selected==true)
   {

   }
   else if (document.getElementById("selection04").selected==true)
   {

   }
}

function allagi2()
{
     if (document.getElementById("select02").selected==true)
     {
         document.getElementById("selectbox01").disabled=false;
     }
}

</script>

</head>



<body>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="logo">

  <select onchange="allagi2()">
  <option id="select01" selected="true">Επιλέξτε</option>
  <option id="select02">Τουρισμό</option>
  <option id="select03">Προϋπολογισμό</option>
  </select>

  <select id="selectbox01" onchange="allagi()" disabled="true">
  <option id="selection01">Selection01</option>
  <option id="selection02">Selection02</option>
  <option id="selection03">Selection03</option>
  <option id="selection04">Selection04</option>
  </select>
</div>
  <div id="chart">



  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

could anyone help me???

Comment: What do you mean by "visualization"?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to solve your issue.

1. The first would be to write the script tag when the selection is made. this approach is a bit tricky since there is a json object involved.
2. The second would be to simply hide the 'visualization' until the user makes the selection. Which can be easily done using CSS.

I used the second approach. 
The graph generated is placed in a DIV with the ID 'chart-0', and since this DIV is not directly editable, I have used css to hide it when the page loads, and to show it when the 2nd selection is made like:

```
else if (document.getElementById("selection02").selected == true) {
    $('#chart-0').css('display', 'block') //show chart if 2nd option is selected
```

As for the second select, the same approach is used. When a non-default option is selected, the second select is displayed using the code below:

```
if ($('#option1').val() != 'Επιλέξτε') {
    $('#selectbox01').css('display', 'block'); //show second option
 } else if ($('#option1').val() == 'Επιλέξτε') { //hide is user reselects default option
    $('#selectbox01').css('display', 'none'); //hide option
    $('#chart-0').css('display', 'none'); //hide chart
 }
```

[Here is a working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/efqYA/12/) and dont forget to include the jquery in your page.